# Translate SQL query into Linq

Tags: sql, linq

I have a problem with translating SQL query into Linq (especially in "group by" part).

SQL:

```
SELECT 
year(ord.OrderDT) as ODate1,
month(ord.OrderDT) as ODate2,
cus.Company as Company,
sum(ord.InvoiceTotal) as TotalRate,
count(ord.InvoiceTotal) as CountOrd
  FROM [dbo].[Customer] as cus
  join [dbo].[Order] as ord on cus.CustomerID=ord.CustomerID
  group by year(ord.OrderDT), month(ord.OrderDT), Company
  order by ODate1 desc, ODate2 desc, Company
```

I tried:

```
var result = (from cus in dbf.Customer
                      join ord in dbf.Order on cus.CustomerId equals ord.CustomerId
                      select new {
                          Year=ord.OrderDt.Year,
                          Month=ord.OrderDt.Month,
                          Company=cus.Company,
                          Rate=ord.InvoiceTotal
     
                      } into t1
                      group t1 by new {t1.Year, t1.Month,t1.Company} into t2
                      select new
                      {
                          Year=t2.FirstOrDefault().Year,
                          Month=t2.FirstOrDefault().Month,
                          Customer=t2.FirstOrDefault().Company,
                          TotalRate=t2.Sum(c=>c.Rate)
                      }         
                      ).Take(10).ToList();
```

But I get the error saying ".FirstOrDefault()' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated". If I try to get rid of "FirstOrDefault" then I do not have intellisense for t2

Entities:

```
 public Customer()
        { 
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string Company { get; set; }
}

 public Order()
        { 
        public int OrderNo { get; set; }
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public DateTime OrderDT { get; set; }
        public decimal InvoiceTotal { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add your entities, your attempts and what does not work for you.

Comment: I added entities and my attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try next select statement:

```
 select new
 {
     Year=t2.Key.Year,
     Month=t2.Key.Month,
     Customer=t2.Key.Company,
     TotalRate=t2.Sum(c=>c.Rate)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The final query looks like this.

```
    var result = (from cus in dbf.Customer
                  join ord in dbf.Order on cus.CustomerId equals ord.CustomerId
                  select new {
                      Year=ord.OrderDt.Year,
                      Month=ord.OrderDt.Month,
                      Company=cus.Company,
                      Rate=ord.InvoiceTotal
 
                  } into t1
                  group t1 by new {t1.Year, t1.Month,t1.Company} into t2
                  orderby t2.Key.Year descending, t2.Key.Month descending,t2.Key.Company ascending
                  
                  select new
                  {
                      Year=t2.Key.Year,
                      Month=t2.Key.Month,
                      Customer=t2.Key.Company,
                      TotalRate=t2.Sum(c=>c.Rate),
                      Count=t2.Count()
                  }         
                  ).ToList();
```